# change dates in processmaker cartable to persian (jalali) date view

Tags: persian, processmaker

someone ask me how Can I show dates in processmaker in persian. I found a way just to pass this duty to him, and solve a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all replace below in : workflow/engine/templates/cases/casesList.js

```
myDate.dateFormat( FORMATS.casesListDateFormat )
```

to

```
 new persianDate(myDate.dateFormat( FORMATS.casesListDateFormat )).format()
```

it needs to include [persianDate](http://babakhani.github.io/PersianWebToolkit/) or any to library workflow/engine/methods/cases/casesListExtJs.php like bellow:

```
echo "<script src='/lib/pmdynaform/libs/datepicker/jalali/persian-date.min.js'></script>";
```

remember to upload js libraries in destination indicated above.

Comment: Thanks, Which files should be modified to change the date in the design pages?

Comment: it depends on the endpoint. tell me more details be able to help.

Comment: What is the best way to contact you?